# Mysql how to find current database, assign it into a string variable

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to do something like this,
1.get the database name (db1) and assign to a string variable
2.the data I need are in db1.out
3.get the data into a table from db1_out

```
set @dbname = SELECT DATABASE();
set @newdb  = concat(@dbname,'_out');
drop table if exists AAA;
create AAA
Select *
from @newdb.BBB;
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: Using a dot as database name is not allowed within MySQL. This is the regex `[0-9,a-z,A-Z$_]` that validates a valid database name so you need to replace the  dot with a underscore.

Comment: thanks, but 
    set @dbname = SELECT DATABASE(); this does not work, so I am not sure how to assign this variable

Comment: `SET @dbname = DATABASE();` should work check mine answer

Comment: Is this running in the MySql console or in an application? I'm asking because this would never work in the MySQL console, since the default behavior is to have the own mysql database selected as you connect to it. It is up to the user that is connecting to MySql to either change the database through the `use` command or via parameter

Comment: I am using MySQL workbench 6.0 on console, and it is not working

Comment: And if it is from an application you don't need to select the database since your application connects to a specific one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SQL should be something like this.

```
SET @dbname = DATABASE();
SET @newdb  = concat(@dbname,'_out');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS AAA;

PREPARE s FROM CONCAT('CREATE AAA SELECT * FROM ', @newdb, '.BBB'); 
EXECUTE s;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```